# convert base64Binary to pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, binary

I have raw data of base64Binary.

```
string base64BinaryStr = "J9JbWFnZ......"
```

How can I make pdf file? I know it need some conversion. Please help me.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Is the raw data to be graphed/plotted, or displayed in a table, or just put in the pdf as raw data?

Comment: c# is used as a developing language.

Answer (score 49):

Step 1 is converting from your base64 string to a byte array:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64BinaryStr);
```

Step 2 is saving the byte array to disk:

```
System.IO.FileStream stream = 
    new FileStream(@"C:\file.pdf", FileMode.CreateNew);
System.IO.BinaryWriter writer = 
    new BinaryWriter(stream);
writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
writer.Close();
```

Comment: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array. in setp 1

Comment: @novicedeveloper: that usually means there's some weird character(s) in your string that make it an invalid Base-64 string. Do you happen to have two double quotes (`""`) at the end of the string?

Comment: Or is this string being passed to an ASP.Net page in the querystring?

Comment: I am not passing it in querystring.

Comment: Wondering why this writes the pdf but not encode the image. my pdf doesnt open.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I need to do the same, but WITHOUT creating a file on disk, cause disk is a very limited resource in my sistem, any idea? Could the FileStream for the .pdf file be created without generating a file on disk?

Answer (score 30):

```
using (System.IO.FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Create("c:\\temp\\file.pdf"))
{
    System.Byte[] byteArray = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64BinaryStr);
    stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
}
```

Comment: question is about converting string bytes to pdf

Answer (score 8):

First convert the Bas64 string to byte[] and write it into a file.

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64BinaryStr); 
File.WriteAllBytes(@"FolderPath\pdfFileName.pdf", bytes );
```

Answer (score 5):

This code does not write any file on the hard drive.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", base64Result.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;");
Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
Response.BinaryWrite(Convert.FromBase64String(base64Result));
```

Note: the variable `base64Result` contains the Base64-String: "JVBERi0xLjMgCiXi48/TIAoxI..."

Comment: ATTENTION: we had to delete this line in our code:

`code`
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", base64Result.Length.ToString());
`code`
Because some browsers couldn't download the whole file.
After we erased the amount of Byte, everything worked just fine.

Let the browsers do the byte-size-calculation by itself! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is run it through any Base64 decoder which will take your data as a string and pass back an array of bytes.  Then, simply write that file out with pdf in the file name.
Or, if you are streaming this back to a browser, simple write the bytes to the output stream, marking the appropriate mime-type in the headers.

Most languages either have built in methods for converted to/from Base64.  Or a simple Google with your specific language will return numerous implementations you can use.  The process of going back and forth to Base64 is pretty straightforward and can be implemented by even novice developers.

Answer (score 4):

base64BinaryStr - from webservice SOAP message

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64BinaryStr);
```