# Have a binary data and need to convert the same to PDF

Tags: pdf, binary, creation

The pdf is getting generated in local but it is corrupted .The message is 'adobe reader could not open because it is either not supported or damaged'.Below is the code i am using .The binary content is a pdf content for sure .Please help ......

```
string path= "E:/J/test1.pdf";

byte[] binrydata = System.Convert.FromBase64String(content);
binrydata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content)

System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
stream.Write(binrydata, 0, binrydata.Length);
stream.Close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert base64Binary to pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626982/convert-base64binary-to-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming content really is a base64 encoded PDF,

```
string path= "E:/J/test1.pdf";

byte[] binrydata = System.Convert.FromBase64String(content);
//Don't do this. Oops.
//binrydata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content)

System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
stream.Write(binrydata, 0, binrydata.Length);
stream.Close();
```